# found a taweez in my room noone knows about where it came from can anyone help translate

Tags: sihr

[image]
I found this in my room today. I dont have much knowledge about these things but i found it pretty concerning and i feel like someone from my relatives is doing sihr.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why should you fear a Taweez when Quran says to fear Allah ..

> "O Children of Israel, remember My favor which I have bestowed upon
> you and fulfill My covenant [upon you] that I will fulfill your
> covenant [from Me], and be afraid of Me. " Quran 2:40

Comment: There is no doubt Allah is the most powerful most beneficient all praise to him. But it also says in the Quran that black magic and sorcery is true in Surah-Al-Baqarah.

Comment: Quran do not say to fear any black magic or sorcery,